# reindex failure - Class 'Magento_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql' not found

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community

I recently upgraded our shop to Magento 1.9.3.2
but we've had indexing issues since.

when I run the reindex command:-

```
php -f /var/www/shell/indexer.php reindexall
```

I get this error:-

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Magento_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql' not found in /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php on line 175

I get the exact same error for these commands:-

```
php -f compiler.php clear
php -f compiler.php disable
```

we tried changing the permissions to 775 on this file (where the class id defined)

```
/var/www/lib/Magento/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
```

but it didn't help.

Can anyone suggest how we can resolve this?

Comment: those 2 compiler commands were

Comment: php -f compiler.php clear

Comment: and: php -f compiler.php disable

Comment: they were an attempt to disable the compiler, but they got the same error as the indexer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a permissions issue. 
I ran the following:

sudo sh ResetFilePermissions.sh

which was at the same level as our magento root
then restarted Apache

I don't know if this script was written by Magento or if it was written in house.
Now I no longer get the error '..Class 'Magento_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql' not found..'. :)

Now I can disable the compiler.

Then I get a new error :/
which I hope has a solution: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Indexer model is not defined.' in /var/www/app/Mage.php:595

Answer (score 0):

Disable compiler by command prompt

```
php -f shell/compiler.php -- disable
php -f shell/compiler.php -- clear
```

Also give permission to your user group

The chown command has the following syntax:

```
chown username:groupname directory
```

Example

```
sudo chown -R root:alex your_root_directory
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: we tried that but got the same error as for the indexer. Thanks tho.

Comment: you used a different syntax so I tried it:

php -f /var/www/shell/compiler.php -- clear

Comment: I got the same error. This:-

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Magento_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql' not found in /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php on line 175

Comment: same for the 2nd statement

Comment: Please check my updated code.

Comment: I ran:- sudo chown -R username:groupname our_magento_root_folder

Comment: and: sudo find our_magento_root_folder -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;

Comment: and: sudo find our_magento_root_folder f -exec chmod 664 {} \;

Comment: then restarted apache. Still got the same error.